# $compile function can not find widget after finding it the first time

Tags: angularjs

I have a search page where user enters a query and then results get updated with `$http` service.

I use `$compile` to display different types of widgets. What happens is when I visit the page first time/reload the page everything works fine but when I set the location using something like following

```
$location.path("/search/" + $scope.q);
```

and that in turn triggers the controller and whole search process, the `$compile` function is unable to find the widget.

What might be the reason for this?

Edit : I found the issue why $compile worked first time but not after that. One more thing I found out later was that view was getting updated i.e. everything started to work fine after  typing something in text box. Issue was/is related to $templateCache. Basically cache callback wasn't happening till there was some user interaction from user like typing in input box or deleting a character from an input which has associated model binding.

After removing cache usage by editing source of angular it worked fine. Raised an issue for this on angular

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1927

Comment: Do you have a fiddle or plunker?

Comment: Whole codebase is large and scattered. Still let me extract relevant bits.